# Streamlit how to add a button to a dataframe

Tags: streamlit

Assume I have a dataframe with several rows like `df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(some_iterator)`. How can I add a button at right of this columns with a on_click function receive one of column named `'id'`

Answer (score 0):

I made something using columns (not the best UI for sure, but it seems to do what what you want). Here is the minimal code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

col1, col2 = st.columns([5, 1])
col1.write("This is column 1")
col2.write("This is column 2")

with col1:
    st.dataframe(pd.DataFrame({"calories": [420, 380, 390], "duration": [50, 40, 45]}))
with col2:
    st.button("Click me", args="id")
```

Here is what is displayed:
[image]